# YUI autocomplete plugin is undefined

Tags: autocomplete, yui

My vary simple code:    var ac = Y.Plugin.AutoComplete("searchInput", "results");

ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'AutoComplete'

do I need to include some specific js file or...?

Answer (score 0):

This probably means you're not calling it the right way. Although I didn't use it before, the documentation says it only takes one parameter, not two strings. See [AutoComplete API](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Plugin.AutoComplete.html) :

> init ( config ) Base
>
> Inherited from BaseCore but overwritten in base/js/Base.js:191
>
> Init lifecycle method, invoked during construction. Fires the init
>   event prior to setting up attributes and invoking initializers for the
>   class hierarchy. Parameters:
>
> ```
> config Object
>
> Object with configuration property name/value pairs
> ```
>
> Returns: Base: A reference to this object

So you should try to create a config object and pass it as parameter.

Alexis